# draw borders vba excel on button with space

Tags: vba, draw

Hi I'm new with VBA need some help here if possible. I am trying to make 3 buttons, each button draws a top-line and a bottom line(i'll provide the excel file too):

the first button draws inside of 5 rows a top and a bottom line.

the second button draws inside of 10 rows a top and a bottom line.

the third button draws inside of 20 rows a top and a bottom line.

What I'm trying to achieve:
every time I press button 1 to keep count if already has been drawn the borders, if I press twice in a row button 1 to keep count if I already have drawn the borders, and draw again after keeping a space of 2 rows in between....Same if I would've pressed Button1, then Button 2. Or button 3.

..I am new with VBA I would love some help....

```
ub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A13:BD23").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A27").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("A27").Select
End Sub
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A4:J8").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("C9").Select
End Sub
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Range("A26:P46").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("G34").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
End Sub
```

DL LINK:
https://mega.nz/#!sgkVATKQ!k-Nq5gpKf4NfW2afEM8wpg_T5RFqT6y2_iqH7lDTM40

Comment: So whichever button is pressed first, it should use the hard-coded range as a starting point, and after that use an offset of two rows from the "previous" range?  But keep the different widths ?

Comment: Yep that's how I am trying to make my file... I don't know how to add the space between rows...but to keep count of previous border..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely followed your description, but try this:

**EDIT** - added a way to reset the "last range" so you can start over.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoFive()
    DoBorders Range("A4:J8")
End Sub

Sub DoTen()
    DoBorders Range("A13:BD23")
End Sub

Sub DoTwenty()
    DoBorders Range("A26:P46")
End Sub

'this is called to reset the starting point to whatever is passed.
Sub ResetStart()
    DoBorders Nothing
End Sub


Sub DoBorders(rng As Range)
    Dim useRange As Range
    Static lastRange As Range

    'handle resetting the "last range"
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set lastRange = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If lastRange Is Nothing Then
        Set useRange = rng

    Else
        Set useRange = lastRange.Cells(1).Offset(lastRange.Rows.Count + 2, 0) _
                                   .Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    End If

    Set lastRange = useRange 'save for next call

    With useRange
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'remove all borders
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```